# Model return values from another file not working with Sequelize.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following code that does not work currently.

```
var config = require('./libs/sequelize-lib.js');
var connection = config.getSequelizeConnection();//Choosing to not pass in variable this time since this should only run via script.
var models = config.setModels(connection);//Creates live references to the models.

//Alter table as needed but do NOT force the change.  If an error occurs we will fix manually.
connection.sync({ alter: true, force: false }).then(function() {
  models.users.create({
    name: 'joe',
    loggedIn: true
  }).then( task => {
    console.log("saved user!!!!!");
  });
  process.exit();//close the nodeJS Script
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

**sequelize-lib.js**

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

exports.getSequelizeConnection = function(stage){
  var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2)); //If this file is being used in a script, this will attempt to get information from the argument stage passed if it exists

  //Change connection settings based on stage variable.  Assume localhost by default.
  var dbname = argv['stage'] ? argv['stage']+"_db"                              : 'localdb';
  var dbuser = argv['stage'] ? process.env.RDS_USERNAME                         : 'admin';
  var dbpass = argv['stage'] ? process.env.RDS_PASSWORD                         : 'local123';
  var dbhost = argv['stage'] ? "database-"+argv['stage']+".whatever.com"  : 'localhost';

  //If state variable used during require overide any arguments passed.
  if(stage){
    dbname = stage+"_db";
    dbuser = process.env.RDS_USERNAME
    dbpass = process.env.RDS_PASSWORD
    dbhost = "database-"+stage+".whatever.com"
  }

  var connection = new Sequelize(dbname,dbuser,dbpass, {
    dialect: 'mysql',
    operatorsAliases: false, //This gets rid of a sequelize deprecated warning , refer https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8417
    host: dbhost
  });
  return connection;
}

exports.setModels = function(connection){
  //Import all the known models for the project.
  const fs = require('fs');
  const dir = __dirname+'/../models';

  var models = {}; //empty model object for adding model instances in file loop below.

  //@JA - Wait until this function finishes ~ hence readdirSync vs regular readdir which is async
  fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(file => {
    console.log(file);
    //Split the .js part of the filename
    var arr = file.split(".");
    var name = arr[0].toLowerCase();
    //Create a modle object using the filename as the reference without the .js pointing to a created sequelize instance of the file.
    models[name] = connection.import(__dirname + "/../models/"+file);
  })

  //Showcase the final model.
  console.log(models);

  return models; //This returns a model with reference to the sequelize models
}
```

I can't get the create command to work however with this setup.  My guess is the variables must not be passing through correctly somehow.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

The create command definitely works because if in the sequelize-lib.js I modify the setModels function to this...

```
exports.setModels = function(connection){
  //Import all the known models for the project.
  const fs = require('fs');
  const dir = __dirname+'/../models';

  var models = {}; //empty model object for adding model instances in file loop below.

  //@JA - Wait until this function finishes ~ hence readdirSync vs regular readdir which is async
  fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(file => {
    console.log(file);
    //Split the .js part of the filename
    var arr = file.split(".");
    var name = arr[0].toLowerCase();
    //Create a modle object using the filename as the reference without the .js pointing to a created sequelize instance of the file.
    models[name] = connection.import(__dirname + "/../models/"+file);
    models[name].create({
      "name":"joe",
      "loggedIn":true
    });
  })

  //Showcase the final model.
  console.log(models);

  return models; //This returns a model with reference to the sequelize models
}
```

Then it works and I see the item added to the database! (refer to proof image below)

[image]

Take note, I am simply running create on the variable at this point.  **What am I doing wrong where the model object is not passing between files correctly?** Weird part is I don't get any errors thrown in the main file?? It's as if everything is defined but empty or something and the command is never run and nothing added to the database.

I tried this in the main file also and no luck.

```
models["users"].create({
    name: 'joe',
    loggedIn: true
  }).then( task => {
    console.log("saved user!!!!!");
  });
```

The purpose of this all is to read models automatically from the model directory and create instances that are ready to go for every model, even if new one's are added in the future.

**UPDATE::**

So I did another test that was interesting, it seems that the create function won't work in the .then() function of the sync command.  It looks like it was passing it correctly though.  After changing the front page to this...

```
var config = require('./libs/sequelize-lib.js');
var connection = config.getSequelizeConnection();//Choosing to not pass in variable this time since this should only run via script.
var models = config.setModels(connection);//Creates live references to the models using connection previosly created.

models["users"].create({
  "name":"joe",
  "loggedIn":true
});

//Alter table as needed but do NOT force the change.  If an error occurs we will fix manually.
connection.sync({ alter: true, force: false }).then(function() {
  process.exit();//close the nodeJS Script
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Doing this seems to get create to work.  I'm not sure if this is good form or not though since the database might not be created at this point? I need a way to get it to work in the sync function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I answered my question finally, but I'm not sure I like the answer.

```
var config = require('./libs/sequelize-lib.js');
var connection = config.getSequelizeConnection();//Choosing to not pass in variable this time since this should only run via script.
var models = config.setModels(connection);//Creates live references to the models using connection previosly created.

//Alter table as needed but do NOT force the change.  If an error occurs we will fix manually.
connection.sync({ alter: false, force: false }).then( () => {
  models["users"].create({
    "name":"joe",
    "loggedIn":true
  }).then( user => {
    console.log("finished, with user.name="+user.name);
    process.exit();
  }).catch( error => {
    console.log("Error Occured");
    console.log(error);
  });
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

turns out that process.exit was triggering before create would occur because create happens async.  This means that all my code will have to constantly be running through callbacks...which seems like a nightmare a bit.  I wonder if there is a better way?